# latency is higher in low traffic with netty

Tags: tcp, netty

In our production environment, a strange problem occurred: latency is higher in low traffic.
Then I build Tcp Server and Client with Netty4 and send data with one connection. Each request is 100kB. The latency in qps(request per second)=1 is much higher than that in in qps=100. 
Conditions:

1. PING latency between server and client is about 2ms.
2. option TCP_NODELAY is turned on both sides.
3. on server side, it will sleep for 20ms util response(simulating prod service).

The test result:

- < 24ms when qps = 100(100kB per request);
- > 35ms when qps = 1 (100kB per request);
- < 23ms when qps = 1 (1kB per request);

Latency with different package size when qps=1

- ping laltency: 1.66ms
- 100kB - 39ms
- 50kB - 32ms
- 20kB - 27.38ms
- 17kB - 26.15ms
- 15kB - 25.9ms
- 10kB - 22.62ms (which is acceptable)

I'd like to find out the cause for bad performance in low traffic. I wonder if it is caused by some Tcp Options.

Comment: What is your question? Please try to be more specific when asking a question.

Comment: Try with TCP_NODELAY turned off. TCP_NODELAY makes performance worse for protocols designed to layer on top of TCP and is only intended as a kludge to be used for protocols not designed to work with TCP. Presumably, since you build a TCP client and server, your protocol is designed to work on top of TCP and should not need a kludge.

Comment: Your issue might be the CPU snoozing. It can take a few ms for a CPU to come back to full power after a break. With the higher load, the CPU may be in a less deep snooze.

Comment: @TheChubbyPanda I want to find out why the latency is higher in low traffic, and get the same performance in low traffic as possible.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I turned off TCP_NODELAY, but no effect. And any suggestion about CPU snoozing? Thanks.

Comment: supplement: latency improves in smaller package(1kB per request) in low traffic.

Comment: Does your protocol do 1 request per connection, or multiple?

Comment: How does the "sleep handler" look like? As the server load increases, Netty gets more bytes per "read" call to the Java NIO layer, and if your sleep handler responds to the "read" calls, rather than to the "real protocol packets", it will seem to work slower with a lower load (if you packets are bigger than 1500 B (1.5KB), you will start noticing this)

Comment: Did you in fact design your protocol to layer efficiently over TCP? For example, does it provide appropriate application-layer acknowledgements to allow ACKs to piggyback? It's most likely either that of CPU power saving. You can test by turning off (or turning down) CPU power saving to see if that's a factor.

Comment: @Ferrybig My protocol is simply 1 request per connection. It is not sleep on read. I have a LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder and customized handler(put request to a delay queue and respond after dequeue). On the other hand, this problem occurred on other servers(like C++ tcp server).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz We didn't turn on CPU power saving as it is production environment. It reproduced not only on my echo server, but also on other server, like C++ TCP server. If it is caused by power saving, request with 1kB could also be in bad performance.

Comment: @MatthewZhang Do you write the entire reply in a single call to the TCP stack? Do you have application-level acknowledgements? Do you really want to have to build up and tear down a new TCP connection for each request?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes, it is a single call for the entire reply. TCP connection keeps for every request but is not rebuilt everytime. The network component Netty does application-level acknowledgement. I wonder if it is caused by some traffic control. Because if the packet is aboult 1kB, there is no latency issue. When the packet is bigger, the latency is times higher. I added detailed latency test results in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, we found out the reason for this high latency low traffic issue. By testing with different package sizes, 14KB was the turn point: if package was not bigger than 14KB, the latency showed as expected, but if package size increased to 15KB, latency went worse. So we tried to update net.ipv4.tcp_init_cwnd from 10 to 100, latency declined since a request with multiple TCP packages could be included in the same sliding window.